# Will I damage my lager if I add lager hops too early?

Tags: hops, lager

Well my beer is just under temperature so I know it will take a bit longer to ferment but I added my lager hops. Do you think this may effect my lager in any way?

Comment: Do you mean "lager yeast" instead of "lager hops"?

Comment: well on the packet it says lager hops

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more information about the process you followed. There are different kits with different instructions. It would help if we knew what you'd done up to now.

Comment: Re: "under temperature": what temperature is it at? What temperature do you think it's supposed to be at?

I, too, have never heard of "lager hops"; hen in the process did you add them?

Comment: Hops are green plant material that you normally add during the boil, but also sometimes to the fermentor. Dry yeast is usually in a sachet, and looks like sand that you add to the fermentor. Can you clarify which it is?

Comment: well on the packet it said lager hops and was like a green plant looked a little bit like pelets and it said add to your fermentor 10 days into fermentation

Comment: i bought a starter kit from the range and a lager kit it said strealise your fermentor and all that then boil so mutch water add the contents of the sachet add lager yeast give it a mix also add dextrose sugar then leave for 14 days but on the 10th day add lager hops a green like pelet on the instructions it says the temprature should be between 20-25c and its mor like 16 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for clarification in the comments. The upshot is:

- fermentation temps externally are 16-17c, although instructions say 20-25c
- hop pellets were added at day 10 to the fermentor

Firstly, this isn't a true lager kit that you have. Lager is made with a different species of yeast compared to Ales, one that ferments typically in the 5-12°C range, while ales ferment in the 14-25°C range. From the temperature guidelines of 20-25°C I can tell you with confidence that what you have in the pack is an ale yeast, not a lager yeast. This is very common with so-called "lager" beer kits - they ship a regular ale yeast to try to make it easier for the brewer so they don't have to chill the beer. As a result, the beer is fruitier and lacks the crispness of a true lager.

However, by reducing the temperature as you did, you reduce the fruitiness of the beer and other possible off-flavors, so you did yourself a favour with the lower temps!

The lower temperature has no bearing on the hops you added, which are unaffected by a few degrees difference temperature. The hops added to the fermentor will give your beer a stronger hop aroma and flavor.

All in all, this beer will probably be better than if you followed the instructions exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make an assumption that the word lager on your hop sachet meant in the sense of storing for a period of time, like the German word that "lager" is derived from. I refer to that as dry hopping. So, you think you've added your dry hops a little too early.

There probably wont be a huge problem with your beer. If your fermentation was almost done, you're better off. Two issues are infection risk and perhaps lessened hop aroma. Because hops are not sterile, adding them during rapid fermentation can increase risk of infection. Secondly, hop aroma can be released with the CO<sub>2</sub> of heavy fermentation, making your final product seem less hoppy.

**TL;DR**: You're probably fine.

Further reading on dry hopping [here](http://byo.com/stories/issue/item/568-dry-hopping-for-great-aroma)